# WPF ListView loses focus for every item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, focus

I'm having a little trouble with the WPF ListView and couldn't find any answer to this. I'm having a simple ListView in a WPF application with a few items in it. I have also attached a GotFocus event-handler on the GotFocus event. It seems that for every selection I do on the ListView also the GotFocus event is fired

xaml-code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="MS" GotFocus="MS_GotFocus"></ListView>

</Grid>
```

cs-code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<string> test = new List<string>();
            test.Add("Item 1");
            test.Add("Item 2");

            MS.ItemsSource = test;
        }

        private void MS_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Focus");
        }
    }
}
```

Has someone also experienced this problem?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: Why would you think that was a problem? And what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You should read on GotFocus event first

Comment: @msedi when you select `ListViewItem` it will get focus so `ListView` will loose it. There is `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` property which tells you if there is keyboard focus somewhere within this control

Comment: Got focus will be fired every time you make a selection, since every time you select an entry, the control gets focus first, which causes the event to be fired.

Comment: OK @dkozl . This is what I thought. I have also read in the MSDN that I should not rely on detecting when the control gets the focus. Is there any realiable way to detect the focus change?